# Conditional action in ViewBinder

Tags: android, android-viewbinder

I wish to disable a line item for my `ListView` (using `SimpleCursorAdapter` with `ViewBinder`), but it doesn't work:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch (viewId) {
          case R.id.my_view_status_value:

int viewVal = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

if(viewVal == 0) {
   //disable this line item
   view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.line_item).setEnabled(false);
} else {
   //enable
   view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.line_item).setEnabled(true);
}
```

When I remove `else`, it disables them randomly, when `if-else` exists, all are enabled. What is going on?

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the `ViewBinder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that `view.getRootView()` returns topmost view (probably ListView), which contains many lines and all of them have id R.id.line_item. So it may return pretty random view.
You can try get list item view using `view.getParent()`